# unmet dependencies libgphoto2-port12_2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1_i386.deb

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg, cleanup

I've got `libgphoto2-port12_2.5.14` errors while `apt upgrade`, 
and they are not solved with `apt -f install`. 
I did not installed anything new, just perform the routinary update, upgrade. 
I saw other similar question on [Unmet dependencies - libgphoto2-port12](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926787/unmet-dependencies-libgphoto2-port12) but it is on hold and I cannot the level to comment.

Tried all their "solutions" without success including `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f` that solve to them.
My conf is:

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-81-generic
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The offending error is:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but 2.5.9-3 is installed 
libgphoto2-port12 : Breaks: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (!= 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1) but 2.5.9-3 is installed
libgphoto2-port12:i386 : Breaks: libgphoto2-port12 (!= 2.5.9-3) but 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

If I try to force:

```
$ sudo apt -f install
....
(Reading database ... 438863 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgphoto2-port12_2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgphoto2-port12:i386 (2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1) over (2.5.9-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/libgphoto2_port-12.mo', which is different from other instances of package libgphoto2-port12:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I need help as I cannot install any package. If someone considers that this is not ubuntu related, please, let me know which is the suitable forum. Thanks

Comment: Could you please try to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -f` (like OP did to resolve the issue in the linked question) and, if that doesn't help, `sudo apt-get install -f libgphoto2-port12:{amd64,i386}/xenial`? If neither helps please [edit] your question to include the output of both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libgphoto2-port122.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1:{i386:amd64} versions was comming from ppa:mutlaqja/ppa not from ubuntu repository. I finally solved it myself by downloading directly 16.04 ubuntu stable versions from http://pkgs.org/download/libgphoto2-port12 with:

```
 $ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb
 $ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgphoto2/libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb
```

Then, installing them with:

```
 $ sudo dpkg -i libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_i386.deb
 $ sudo dpkg -i libgphoto2-port12_2.5.10-3_amd64.deb
```

Finally, I removed the offending ppa (temporary until bug solution) with:

```
 $ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mutlaqja/ppa
```

After, I reboot to clean cache and execute standards apt-get update and upgrade, without errors. Now I am free again to install new packages.

Answer (score -1):

"libgphoto2-port12 : Breaks: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (!= 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1)"

the 64 bit and 32 bit versions have to be the same.

either upgrade libphoto2-port12 to ver 2.5.14 or downgrade libphoto2-port12;I386 TO VER 2.5.9-3

Comment: Apparently libgphoto2-port12:amd64 is already in 2.5.14

   $ apt-cache policy libgphoto2-port12:amd64
   libgphoto2-port12:
     Installed: 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1
     Candidate: 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1
     Version table:
   *** 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1 500
          500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mutlaqja/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       2.5.9-3 500
          500 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: sorry got it backwards. the 32 bit version needs uppgrading

Comment: I finally remove wine1.8, libsane, libgphoto2-6 and even gvfs-backends to remove dependencies of libgphot2-port12, after a reboot I manage to run apt upgrade and reinstall everything above, and now got both versions of libgphoto2-por12 {amd64&ie86} in synch. Sincerely, I do not know which one was the cause. I miss a tool to cleanup dpkg when forced install does not solve it and system stall

Comment: likely one of the packages you reinstalled upgraded as well.

Comment: I have another identical ubuntu installation pc that got the same issue. Try former removal and boot, or upgrade of libgphoto2-poer12:ir86 to 2.5.14+201706200750~ubuntu16.04.1 version and issue persist. Not solved yet then.

Comment: do you have aptitude? maybe it will show what is going on

Comment: no. I did read that option but I cannot install it. I cannot downgrade libgphoto2-port12 or upgrade libgphoto2-port:i386.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)